# convert standard C++ string to String^

Tags: string, visual-c++, c++-cli, stdstring

I want to convert to std::string  to System::String^ in Visual C++ environment. I know that we can convert System::String to std::string by the `MarshalString` Function as below:

```
void MarshalString ( String ^ s, string& os ) {
    using namespace Runtime::InteropServices;
    const char* chars = 
        (const char*)(Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(s)).ToPointer();
    os = chars;
    Marshal::FreeHGlobal(IntPtr((void*)chars));
}
```

I can't find the way to convert std::string to System::String but I found that System::String has constructor with argument as below :

```
System::String(Char* value, Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
```

and i try to use code like below, but it can not give me a correct solution :

```
std::string str1 = "MyString";
System::String^ str = new System::String(str1.c_str(), 0, str1.length());
```

What wrong happen in my code?

Comment: The two pieces of code are not doing the same thing: `MarshalString` converts `String ^ s` to `wstring`, while your snippet converts from `string` to `String ^ s` (i.e. the other way around).

Comment: The problem with your attempt is that `System::Char` is a 16 bit value, but `char` is Visual C++ is an 8 bit value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft provide their [C++ Suppport Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177045%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) with Visual Studio to facilitate interaction between C++ and C++/CLI. That library provides the template function [`marshal_as`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384859%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) which will convert a `std::string` to a `System::String^` for you:

```
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>

std::string stdString;
System::String^ systemString = msclr::interop::marshal_as<System::String^>(stdString);
```